# Powershell Subst Command

Tags: powershell

How do I properly invoke the Subst command from my powershell profile?

Here is what I have tried:

I have the following function in my powershell profile:

```
function aa1 {
  Subst "q:" /D
  Subst "q:" $tjb.mypath
}
```

It works when I call it from the command line, but if I call it from my powershell profile, with the line:

```
aa1
```

It gives me the following error upon the start of a new powershell function:

```
Invalid parameter -q:
```

However, I know that the first line of the function works correctly because the q: drive disappears.

Here is an example of the output from the above commands:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Invalid parameter - Q:
Invalid parameter - q:
** snip Other unrelated stuff**
> aa1
Invalid parameter - Q:
>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do `subst q: /d` when q: is not already a substituted drive, you will get this error

Answer (score 1):

I recommend testing if the drive already exists before running subst /D

```
if(Test-Path -Path "q:" -IsValid) {
    # Unsubst the existing q: to make space for a new one
    subst "q:" /D
}
Subst "q:" $tjb.mypath
```